# How to export a fine-tuned SetFit model to ONNX format?

Tags: python, pytorch, onnx, sentence-transformers

SetFit has native functionality for exporting to ONNX, but there's no real documentation on how to do it. What should be passed in for `setfit_model` and `inputs` parameters in the `export_onnx_setfit_model` function?

```
# Load locally stored pre-trained model
setfit_model = SetFitModel.from_pretrained("path/to/my/model", local_files_only=True)

# Create SetFit onnx wrapper
onnx_setfit_model = OnnxSetFitModel(model_body=setfit_model.model_body)

# Export model
export_onnx_setfit_model(setfit_model=onnx_setfit_model, inputs=???, output_path="path/to/output")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you found the answer for this yourself, but they have provided a notebook showing how to export your SetFitModel to ONNX here: https://github.com/huggingface/setfit/blob/main/notebooks/onnx_model_export.ipynb

Basically like this:

```
from setfit.exporters.onnx import export_onnx

# Export the sklearn based model
output_path = "my_setfit_model.onnx"
export_onnx(setfit_model.model_body,
            setfit_model.model_head,
            opset=12,
            output_path=output_path)
```